# How do I get the current record ID from within a Visualforce Lightning component (without using a Standard Controller)?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components

How do I get the record ID of the current record (regardless of object type) when I am writing Visualforce / Apex that is running inside of a Visualforce Page included in a lightning page layout via a lightning Visualforce Page component?

This question was originally marked as a duplicate - [Accessing Record Id inside a lightning app page component (visualforce page used as component) controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164621/accessing-record-id-inside-a-lightning-app-page-component-visualforce-page-used)

The solution described is to use a Standard Controller plus an extension. In my case since this page could appear on any object layout (i.e. Account, Opportunity, Case etc...) and because as I understand it a Standard Controller requires an object literal I don't think this method is viable to grab the ID and utilize the same VF Page across all potential objects it may be placed on.

Answer (score 1):

Is using the recordId interface within the Lightning Component an option?

Such as:

```
    <aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sObjectName" type="String" />
    <b>{!v.recordId} </b><br/>
    <b>{!v.sObjectName} </b><br/>
</aura:component>
```

I am not sure if this solves the visualforce part of your issue though.

Comment: This might be possible if I was including the VisualForce page via an IFrame in a custom lightning component. I did attempt this but ran into some issues with CRSS when trying to use the 3rd party library that I incorporate into the VF Page.

When using the VF Page Component I don't get the CRSS issues but left with the challenge of trying to get the ID without being able to leverage a custom lightning component.